# pip installing flake8 in a Python3 virtualenv installs flake8 for python 2.7 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, flake8

I'm trying to set atom up correctly, and the `linter-flake8` package is annoying me by pointing out syntax errors which aren't there, because it's using a python 2 flake8.

Doubly annoying is that when such an error is pointed out in a file, the rest of the file isn't linted, making finding unused imports that much harder.

I set the executable path in the settings to point to the right binary after pip installing it, but the same errors occur.

```
$ which python
/Users/asday/.virtualenvs/_/bin/python
$ which pip
/Users/asday/.virtualenvs/_/bin/pip
$ pip install flake8
[...]
$ which flake8
/Users/asday/.virtualenvs/_/bin/flake8
$ python -V
Python 3.5.1
$ pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /Users/asday/.virtualenvs/_/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
$ flake8 --version
2.5.4 (pep8: 1.7.0, pyflakes: 1.0.0, mccabe: 0.4.0) CPython 2.7.11 on Darwin
$ flake8 .
./test.py:9:14: E901 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where test.py is simply:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


kwargs = {}

f(
    a=1,
    **kwargs,
)
```

How do I get flake8 to install with the right version of python on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the flake 8 project from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8 then use

```
pip install file.whl
```

This way you can just install it from your local python and it should install as python 3.

Comment: No good.  `-e` is looking for a repository and exits with an error.  Without -e, it's the exact same as installing with `pip install flake8`.

Comment: Maybe try to use pip3 install

Comment: I am doing; I'm in a python3 virtual env, so `pip3` is the same as `pip`.

Comment: that's really strange then, the wheel file should install it as 3.0.4 for the version with it working in python 3. Maybe try: python -m pip install SomePackage

Comment: Bizarrely, today, it does work.  Perhaps there was something hanging around in that terminal window that was causing it to use system python for whatever reason?

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't pip or flake8, it's your PATH variable. What you need to do is `python -m flake8` to get it to use the one in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

Use pip3 install for Python 3.x

Comment: This was already suggested, and wasn't the issue, as in a python3 virtual env, `pip3` and `pip` are equivalent.